# Add leading 0's to zipcode is the length is less than 5 Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update, zipcode

I have a table that includes zip codes but for zips where there is a leading 0 or 0's they are excluded - I have

```
ALTER cbsa_locations CHANGE zip zip CHAR(5);
UPDATE cbsa_locations SET zip=LPAD(zip, 5, '0');
```

which works in changing the table in sandbox. But it doesn't work in our data visualization software. Is there a way to update the zip in a query and then join that table to another one on the zip code in the same query.

Ex. brokerage_coverage table has brokerage_code, zip and the cbsa_locations table has zip city, state, county. I want to join those on zip to get the county for brokerage_coverage but cbsa_locations zip field is missing the leading 0's.

```
select bc.brokerage_code,
          bc.zip,
          cbsa.county
          from brokerage_coverage bc
          join cbsa_locations cbsa on cbsa.zip = bc.zip
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: `... join cbsa_locations  to_char(cbsa_zip::int, '00000')  = bc.zip`

Answer (score 0):

You can pad the column with the missing 0 in the join condition:

```
select bc.brokerage_code,
       bc.zip,
       cbsa.county
from brokerage_coverage bc
   join cbsa_locations cbsa on cbsa.zip = lpad(bc.zip, 5, '0')
```

Comment: that join worked but it looks like the dataset is excluding the zips with a leading 0

Comment: Please post [mre].